# I tried to code snake game and the gaming is working perfectly fine. I am just having a single error and am unable to figure out the reason

Tags: c++, project

The problem I am getting is, whenever a new 'S' is added to the body it does not erase from the screen, it appears there. I have tried different approaches but not getting the perfect results.

I have given the code and the problem is clearly visible when the program runs. Please help me out and please suggest some techniques to improve the code and performance. This is my first ever project and any help will be beneficial.

```cpp
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define UP 72
#define DOWN 80
#define LEFT 75
#define RIGHT 77
int X[50]={0},FX;
int Y[50]={0},FY;
int DIR=RIGHT;
int gameover=0;
int score=0;
int count=0;
void welcome()
{
   for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
   {
      gotoxy(25,i);
      cout<<"!!! Welcome to SNAKE GAME !!!";
      delay(300);
      clrscr();
   }
   gotoxy(25,10);
   cout<<"!!! Welcome to SNAKE GAME !!!";
   getch();
}
void end()
{
   gotoxy(30,10);
   cout<<"#Thanks for playing";
   getch();
}
int genrandom()
{
   return ((rand()%(39-4+1))+4);
}
void fruit()
{
   FX=genrandom();
   FY=FX/2;
   gotoxy(FX,FY);
   cout<<"F";
}
void box()
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<20;i++)
   {
      cout<<"# ";
   }
   cout<<"\n";
   for(i=0;i<19;i++)
   cout<<"#                                     #\n";
   for(i=0;i<20;i++)
   {
      cout<<"# ";
   }
}
void start()
{
   srand(time(0));
   box();
   X[0]=genrandom();
   Y[0]=(X[0]/2);
   gotoxy(X[0],Y[0]);
   cout<<"&";
   fruit();
   getch();
}
void play()
{
int ch,preX,preY,i;
   while(gameover==0)
   {
       while(!kbhit())
       {
       delay(150);
       for(i=count;i>0;i--)
       {
           X[i]=X[i-1];
           Y[i]=Y[i-1];
       }
       preX=X[count];
       preY=Y[count];
       if(DIR==UP)
       Y[0]--;
       if(DIR==DOWN)
       Y[0]++;
       if(DIR==RIGHT)
       X[0]=X[0]+2;
       if(DIR==LEFT)
       X[0]=X[0]-2;
       if(X[0]==1||X[0]==39||Y[0]==1||Y[0]==21)
       {
           gameover=1;
           clrscr();
           gotoxy(30,10);
           cout<<"YOU LOST";
           break;
       }
       if((FX==X[0]||FX==X[0]+1||FX==X[0]-1)&&FY==Y[0])
       {
          gotoxy(FX,FY);
          cout<<" ";
          score=score+10;
          gotoxy(42,1);
          cout<<"Score: "<<score;
          fruit();
          count++;
          if(DIR==UP)
          {
         Y[count]=Y[count-1]+1;
          }
          if(DIR==DOWN)
          {
         Y[count]=Y[count-1]-1;
          }
          if(DIR==RIGHT)
          {
         X[count]=X[count-1]-1;
          }
          if(DIR==LEFT)
          {
         X[count]=X[count-1]+1;
          }
       }
       for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
       {
           gotoxy(X[i],Y[i]);
           cout<<"S";
       }
       gotoxy(preX,preY);
       cout<<" ";
       }
       ch=getch();
       if(ch==88||ch==120)
       {
       gameover=1;
       break;
       }
       else
       DIR=ch;
   }
}
void main()
{
   clrscr();
   welcome();
   clrscr();
   start();
   play();
   getch();
   clrscr();
   end();
}
```

Comment: Using `<iostream.h>` indicates that you are using a disastrously antique C++ compiler.  (1) Don't tag C++ questions with C.  (2) Get a compiler that is aware that the current C++ standard is C++17 (with C++20 due out soon).  Using `<iostream.h>` has been somewhere between an extremely bad idea to totally unsupported since the C++98 standard was released.  You're using a compiler that is quite possibly older than you are — that is bad news.  (Given `<conio.h>` and `<dos.h>`, I'd guess it is Turbo C++ that you're using.  Get the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) and `g++` — it too is free and.)

Comment: Learn to use the gdb debugger from the command line. It's fairly simple, you can set breakpoints, step through the code - it takes a little bit of learning, but not too much, and with a little practice you can identify the specific points in the code that are causing problems very quickly.